# How to add text to array in cycle

Tags: php, arrays, cycle

I get some information from database! I need to place it on the array! How to add value to array in cycle???
I did this, but it did not wirk:

```
 a[]='';   
 while ($p = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryAns)) {
            $countAnswers++;
            a[] = $p['name'];
            $arr .= $countAnswers.") "." ".$p['name']."\n";
}
```

Comment: couldn't understand your question...can you clarify???

Comment: please share what output you need? and explore it more

Comment: How to add value to array in cycle?

Comment: I think you should understand the basics of arrays http://www.technofusions.com/introduction-to-arrays-in-php/

Comment: I know how do array! But I dont understand how add values to it in cycle

Comment: Give your expected output

Comment: So, what is `a[]`?

Comment: if `a[]` is the array your trying to add into then it'll just produce a syntax error because `a` is not a variable (should be erroring out before the loop where you have `a[]=''; `)

Answer (score 0):

The .= operator in PHP is used to concatenate strings. In order to append a new element to your array you need to do:

```
array_push($arr, $countAnswers.") "." ".$p['name']."\n");
```